# Count and Join did not work on phalcon framework

Tags: php, mysqli, phalcon

I have the code like this

```
$phql = "SELECT COUNT(a.id) FROM UserParkingIn a JOIN UserVehicle b ON a.userVehicleId = b.id WHERE b.vehicleTypeId = 1";
$result = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql);
echo $result;
```

in UserParkingIn Table I have example id = 10, userVehicleId = 2
in UserVehicle Table I have example id =10, userVehicleId = 2, vehicleTypeId = 1

It return empty, but when I execute this query in phpMyAdmin I use this sql logic it return right number.

```
SELECT COUNT(a.id) FROM user_parking_in a JOIN user_vehicle b ON a.userVehicleId = b.id WHERE b.vehicleTypeId=1;
```

and it return number 7

Can someone explain why this return error?
Thank you.

Comment: I think if your gonna use a framework it makes sense to use their built in ORM query builder. Can be a bit confusing at first but makes it a lot cleaner and easier to build your queries in the long run. I think it also makes it easier to debug these issues. the documentation shows some good examples https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#finding-records

Comment: @JasonJoslin the ORM didn't support count with JOIN two tables where condition is at joined table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution that id I used to count must set an alias to be like quota like this.

```
$query = $this->modelsManager->createQuery("SELECT COUNT(a.id) as quota FROM UserParkingIn a JOIN UserVehicle b ON a.userVehicleId = b.id WHERE a.ospoId = '$ospoId' ");
            $records  = $query->execute();
            foreach($records as $record){
                $parkingUsed = $record->quota;
            }
```

and now it is working.